# SQL Server - Select distinct with most recent date plus other results

Tags: sql-server, distinct

Having the registers above, how can I get the code (taking into account that the first 3 codes are the same) that has most recent date,
and still show the other results?

```
id  |  agency   |  code     |   date
1   |  11111    |  12345    |   2018-09-25 00:01:10.000
2   |  11111    |  12345    |   2018-09-25 00:01:20.000
3   |  11111    |  12345    |   2018-09-25 00:01:30.000
4   |  22222    |  23456    |   2018-09-25 00:02:00.000
7   |  33333    |  54321    |   2018-09-25 00:02:10.000
```

What I would like to have is:

```
id  |  agency   |  code     |   date
3   |  11111    |  12345    |   2018-09-25 00:01:30.000
4   |  22222    |  23456    |   2018-09-25 00:02:00.000
7   |  33333    |  54321    |   2018-09-25 00:02:10.000
```

Thanks in advance for any further help!

Comment: What's the relationship between agency and code? Can an agency be related to more than one code?

Comment: @Anderson: Is it mandatory to have ID as MAX_VALUE??

Answer (score 0):

Think "filtering".  In this case, with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.agency = t.agency);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two situations to deal with.
(1) Get max date of each agency from youTable. This can be done by using aggregate function(max()) and group by agency.

(2) Select all record from yourTable and inner join with the results from (1).

```
select t1.id, t1.agency,t1.code,t1.date 
from yourTable t1 
    inner join 
    (
        --only most recent of each agency
        select max(date) date,agency from yourTable group by agency
    ) t2 on t1.[date]=t2.[date] and t1.agency=t2.agency
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing some discussion on why it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Use ROW_NUMBER value**

---

This will help you.

You can get the ROW_NUMBER value for each row by your distinct columns.
Set it in order by of your DATE column.

```
SELECT  *
FROM  (
        SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AGENCY, CODE ORDER BY date_column) AS ROW_NUMBER
        FROM  table_name
    ) AS ROWS
WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 1
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/98609/3)